# CSS: Two inputs side by side

Tags: css, input

How can I make this:

[image]

Look like this:

[image]

I.e have the two fields and the sign in buttons side by side? Thanks

Comment: Can you provide your html-code?

Answer (score 7):

Give both fields a different class and assign to the most left one `float:left;`

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" class="field1"/>
<input type="text" class="field2"/>
```

**CSS:**

```
.field1 {
   float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume this is more what you need:
http://jsfiddle.net/mrchris2013/NtVuq/12/

HTML:

```
<label>Username</label>
<label>Password</label>

<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />

<input type="button" value="Login" />
```

CSS:

```
label, input[type=text] {
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
}

label + input[type=text] {
    clear: left;
}

input[type=button] {
    float: left;
}
```